# Woocommerce auto populates/copies order meta/field from vale of user profile customer field

Tags: php, wordpress, function, woocommerce, hook-woocommerce

G'day, I'm trying to create a function which auto populates/copies woocommerce order meta/field from value of WP user profile custom field. [I want it to work even if I create a new order from a new order page.]

```
// billing_tax_number  -> Custom Order Meta / Field TXT
// company_tax_number  -> Custom Profile Field TXT

add_action( 'woocommerce_checkout_create_order', 'update_order_tax_data', 30, 2 );
function update_order_tax_data( $order, $posted_data ) {
    $user_id = $order->get_customer_id(); // Get user ID

    if( empty($user_id) || $user_id == 0 )
        return; // exit

  $gst_data  = $order->get_billing_tax_number(); // Get TAX number (checking)

    if( empty($gst_data) ){
        $gst_data = get_user_meta( $user_id, 'billing_tax_number', true );
        if( empty($gst_data) )
            $gst_data = get_user_meta( $user_id, 'company_tax_number', true );

        $order->set_billing_tax_number($gst_data); // Save last name
    }
    
    
}
```

I thank you in advance for your time and sharing expertise in advance.

Answer (score 0):

**Answer:**

```
  // billing_tax_number  -> Custom Order Meta / Field TXT
    // company_tax_number  -> Custom Profile Field TXT
    
    add_action( 'woocommerce_checkout_create_order', 'update_order_tax_data', 30, 2 );
    function update_order_tax_data( $order, $posted_data ) {
        $user_id = $order->get_customer_id(); // Get user ID
    
        if( empty($user_id) || $user_id == 0 )
        
            return; // exit
    
      $tax_data  = $order->get_meta('billing_tax_number'); // Get TAX number (checking)
    
        if( empty($tax_data) ){
    
            $tax_data = get_user_meta( $user_id, 'billing_tax_number', true );
            
            if( empty($tax_data) )
            
                $tax_data = get_user_meta( $user_id, 'company_tax_number', true );
    
            $order->add_meta_data('billing_tax_number', $tax_data); // Save tax number
        }    
    }
```

Regards